# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Limit

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, iis-6, cors

I have set up our public facing website with the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * so that we can use JSON and AJAX. However, what I really want to do is limit it to only certain servers. The requests should only ever come from a few servers that we control. I am having trouble finding something works without adding in code (example psuedo-code):

```
for each domain in myDomains
    addheader Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain
next
```

Is it possible to just add multiple "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in IIS under the HTTP Headers tab? I know that it is possible to actually add it to IIS, but does it work?

*Example:*

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1 (use using home as IP example)
```

Using *Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ** is just to insecure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers are not allowed. You can only have one `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, and that header can only have one origin value or `*` (e.g. you can't have multiple space-separated origins).

Your best option is to read the incoming Origin header, check its value against a whitelist, and only emit the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header if the Origin is allowed. Here's an example in pseudo-code:

```
origin = request.getHeader('Origin');
for each domain in myDomains
  if (domain == origin)
    // Add header if the origin is whitelisted
    addheader Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain
    return
// Otherwise exit the for loop without adding any headers.
```

Comment: Well that was what I was trying to avoid, but you confirmed what I have been reading for the last couple of hours. I was just hoping for a server config change and not an emergency code push. Thanks.

Comment: Where do I add that?

Comment: What is the `addHeader` function?